# WaitForSeconds isn't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a class which is changing the player speed. Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MultiplySpeed : MonoBehaviour {
    public int multiplier = 2;
    public Controls player;
    bool flag = false;
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider c){
        if(c.tag == "Player"){
            player = c.gameObject.GetComponent<Controls>();
            if(!flag){
                multiplySpeed();
                StartCoroutine(powerUp());
            }
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator powerUp(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
        backToNormal ();
        StopCoroutine(powerUp ());
    }
    public void multiplySpeed(){
        player.speed = player.speed * multiplier;
    }
    public void backToNormal(){
        player.speed = player.speed/ multiplier;
    }
}
```

I have two problems, the first one is that after starting the coroutine and the flag variable is set to true, the method `OnTriggerExit` is called once again, and the flag is false and everything is executed again. The second problem is that the method `backToNormal` seems like it's never executed, it simply multiplies the speed and never take it back to normal.  Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
After trying the method suggested by Lasse Klüver, here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MultiplySpeed : MonoBehaviour {
    public int multiplier = 2;
    public Controls player;
    bool flag = false;
    float timer = 5.0f;
    void update(){
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer == 0) {
            backToNormal();
            timer = -1f;
        }

    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider c){
        if(c.tag == "Player"){
            player = c.gameObject.GetComponent<Controls>();
            if(!flag){
                timer = 5.0f;
                flag = true;
                multiplySpeed();
            }
        }
    }
    public void multiplySpeed(){
        player.speed = player.speed * multiplier;
    }
    public void backToNormal(){
        player.speed = player.speed/ multiplier;
    }
}
```

However I have exactly the same problems.

Comment: You don't need the `StopCoroutine` call: coroutines run once, finishing when they return. I'm not sure what calling `StopCoroutine` on a new coroutine does. (See [http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html).)

Comment: Can you provide more detailed description of the logic behind the script? What is the purpose of the flag?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MultiplySpeed : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int multiplier = 2;
    public Controls player;
    bool flag = false;
    float timer = 5.0f;
    bool countDown = false;

    void update()
    {
        if (countDown)
        {
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer <= 0)
            {
                backToNormal();
                countDown = false;
            }
        }

    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider c)
    {
        if (c.tag == "Player")
        {
            player = c.gameObject.GetComponent<Controls>();
            if (!flag)
            {
                countDown = true;
                timer = 5.0f;
                flag = true;
                multiplySpeed();
            }
        }
    }
    public void multiplySpeed()
    {
        player.speed = player.speed * multiplier;
    }
    public void backToNormal()
    {
        player.speed = player.speed / multiplier;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to count the frames, I want to count the seconds.

Comment: I added an example to my answer. The counter variable will be 0 after 3 seconds in this scenario.

Comment: I have exactly the same problems as before, i have updated the question with my new code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the players speed for a given amount of time (5 seconds) if it hits a power up I would go the other way around. I would not do the timing stuff inside the power up – because I think it should be destroyed immediately after a player hit it – I would do it from a script attached to the player.
Something like the following should work:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SpeedBoostPowerUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
    {
        if(c.tag == "Player")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could add your speed boost code inside your move component (Controls.cs). You could do something like that (I didn't want to change too much of your code):

```
// INSIDE CONTROLS COMPONENT
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
{
    if(c.tag == "SpeedBoostPowerUp")
    {
        if (!flag)
        {
            StartCorouting(BoostSpeed);
        }
    }
}

public void MultiplySpeed()
{
    this.speed = this.speed * this.multiplier;
}

public void BackToNormal()
{
    this.speed = this.speed / this.multiplier;
}

private IEnumerator BoostSpeed()
{
    flag = true;
    MultiplySpeed();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    BackToNormal();
    flag = false;
}
```

Of course you need to tag your power up GameObject with the "SpeedBoostPowerUp" tag. The flag is used, so that you can't have multiple speed boosts at once.
This should work fine if you use "static" power ups – so power ups that have a fixed behaviour. If you want to give the player a random boost etc. if it hits the power up – like in mario kart for instance – I would structure this differntly. But this would be too complex for what you want to achieve I guess.

Note: I would not go back to normal speed by *speed = speed / multiplier* but instead use a variable to store the speed before multiplying it, because it should be less error prone. Like that:

```
private float speedBeforeBoost;

public void MultiplySpeed()
{
    this.speedBeforeBoost = this.speed;
    this.speed *= this.multiplier;
}

public void BackToNormal()
{
    this.speed = this.speedBeforeBoost;
}
```